# PHP proc_open does not return correct value

Tags: php

I am trying to run SSH command from PHP file.

```
ssh alpv3cm1.aldc.att.com -l eda -n cat /opt/app/cust/apphome/enbapp/ogs/EMAS/cyc_rebill_go_ahead.txt |wc -l
```

The output of above command is 7.

I am using below PHP code to get the value inside variable using prod_open() function.

```
 <?php
           $descriptorspec = array(
                    0 => array("pipe", "r"),
                    1 => array("pipe", "w"),
                    2 => array("file", "/tmp/error-output.txt", "a")
            );

            $process = proc_open('ssh alpv3cm1.aldc.att.com -l eda -n cat /opt/app/cust/apphome/enbapp/ogs/EMAS/cyc_rebill_go_ahead.txt |wc -l',$descriptorspec, $pipes);

            if (is_resource($process)) {

                    fclose($pipes[1]);

                    $return_value = proc_close($process);
                    echo $return_value
                    exec_stat_dml($upd);
                    }
```

?>

But i am getting return value as 1 instead of 7. Please help me out.

Comment: Straight from the Manual: proc_close() waits for the process to terminate, and returns its exit code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.